# is_unique syntax in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table entity called position. I am storing the value using smallint(2) datatype, where I intend to store the value from 0 to 9 (max). I want to make sure the value is just a single integer and an integer should not be repeated at any cost. There should be a unique value assigned to each id of the position entity in the table ranging from 0 to 9. How do I achieve it? Is there any mysql syntax for that?

I am using MySQL with PHP.

here is the mysql table could someone add me the unique code and show

```
CREATE TABLE `advertisements` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`position` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
`active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

is this the correct syntax?

```
CREATE TABLE `advertisements` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`position` smallint(2) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must define that column as `UNIQUE`.

```
ALTER TABLE `a` ADD UNIQUE (
    `id`
)
```

Comment: thank you i did that and it is working pretty cool, mysql is straight away rejecting the duplicates.. thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts:

- How do I ensure that a value is unique in a column?

Add a unique index.

- How do I restrict a value to be in the range 0 to 9?

You can add a foreign key constraint to a table that lists the allowed values.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `smallint(2)` and `smallint(1234)` and `smallint` are exactly the same in MySQL.  The numeric argument is not a limit on the length or the range of values, it's only a hint for display width.  MySQL's `smallint` is a 16-bit integer, with a range from -32768 to 32767.  `smallint unsigned` has a range from 0 to 65535.

You can ensure no duplicates exist in a column by declaring a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  position SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (position)
);
```

To restrict the values to the range 0 to 9, there are a few options:

- Write a trigger that causes an error if you try to store a value outside the range.

  ```
  DELIMITER //
  CREATE TRIGGER ZeroToNine BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      DECLARE p SMALLINT;
      IF (NEW.position NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 9) THEN
          SET p = 'Position must be between 0 and 9';
      END IF;
  END //
  DELIMITER ;
  ```
- Use a foreign key constraint so the column references a table that you populate with the values 0 to 9.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE ZeroToNine (
    position SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
  INSERT INTO ZeroToNine VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);

  CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    position SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (position),
    FOREIGN KEY (position) REFERENCES ZeroToNine (position)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
  ```
- Other databases also support a `CHECK` constraint, but MySQL unfortunately doesn't support this feature.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    position SMALLINT NOT NULL
      CHECK (position BETWEEN 0 AND 9),
    UNIQUE KEY (position)
  );
  ```

Comment: wow, that is one of the best answer i have got from anyone so far. thank you so much Bill, i really appreciate your effort writing down the bunch of codes to explain me.. thank you once again.